# How to dispatch an empty action?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5, ngrx

I am using [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects).

How can I dispatch an empty action?

This is how I am doing now:

```
 @Effect() foo$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(Actions.FOO)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => ({ action, state }))
    .map(({ action, state }) => {
      if (state.foo.isCool) {
        return { type: Actions.BAR };
      } else {
        return { type: 'NOT_EXIST' };
      }
    });
```

Since I have to return an action, I am using `return { type: 'NOT_EXIST' };`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've used similar unknown actions, but usually in the context of unit tests for reducers.

If you are uneasy about doing the same in an effect, you could conditionally emit an action using `mergeMap`, `Observable.of()` and `Observable.empty()` instead:

```
@Effect() foo$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(ChatActions.FOO)
  .withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => ({ action, state }))
  .mergeMap(({ action, state }) => {
    if (state.foo.isCool) {
      return Observable.of({ type: Actions.BAR });
    } else {
      return Observable.empty();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 22):

The choosen answer does not work with rxjs6 any more. So here is another approach.

Although I prefer filtering for most cases as described in an another answer, using flatMap can sometimes be handy, especially when you are doing complex stuff, too complicated for a filter function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EMPTY, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SomeEffects {
  @Effect()
  someEffect$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType(SomeActionTypes.Action),
    flatMap((action) => {
      if (action.payload.isNotFunny) {
        return of(new CryInMySleepAction());
      } else {
        return EMPTY;
      }
    }),
  );

  constructor(
    private _actions$: Actions,
  ) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

As of ngrx 8 you'll get a run-time error if you try to dispatch an empty action, so I think just filter them out so they're not dispatched.

```
@Effect() foo$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(Actions.FOO),
    withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => ({ action, state })),
    map(({ action, state }) => {
      if (state.foo.isCool) {
        return { type: Actions.BAR };
      }
    }),
    filter(action => !!action)
);
```

Comment: Works like charm in RxJs ~6.6.3, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

I'd do it the following way:

```
@Effect() foo$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(Actions.FOO)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => ({ action, state }))
    .filter(({ action, state }) => state.foo.isCool)
    .map(({ action, state }) => {
      return { type: Actions.BAR };
    });
```

Comment: `filter` is a really nice choice, in this way stream doesn't emit action until the condition is met, and we don't need to throw _empty_ action

Answer (score 12):

The solution I was looking for involved using `@Effect({ dispatch: false })`.

```
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  logThisEffect$: Observable<void> = this.actions$
    .ofType(dataActions.LOG_THIS_EFFECT)
    .pipe(map(() => console.log('logThisEffect$ called')));
```

Comment: This is wrong, in his code he wants to dispatch an action sometimes, and sometimes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

With `"rxjs": "~6.6.6"`, the flatmap has been depricated with merge map we can use the same behaviour

```
import { map, switchMap, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

    addCategorie$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(ADD_CATEGORY),
          mergeMap((category) => this.categoryService.post(category.isCategoryOrVendor, category.model)
            .pipe(
              mergeMap(() => {
                this.backService.back();
                return EMPTY;
              }),
              catchError((error) => of(CATEGORY_ERROR(error)))
            )
          )
        )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another case (without "of", "Observables" and etc.):

```
switchMap(([, projectId]) => {
  const result: Action[] = [];

  if (projectId === null) {
    return result;
  }

  result.push(GetAction({
    filter: {
      projectId,
    },
  }));

  // a lot of another cases

  return result;
}),
```

Answer (score -3):

If you do not want to dispatch an action, then just set `dispatch` to false:

```
 @Effect()
  foo$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(Actions.FOO),
      map(t => [])
    ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```