# Why must must ngrx / redux effects return actions? Is using a noop action like elm considered bad practice?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I'm using a redux-style state management design with Angular and ngrx/store and ngrx/effects. Whenever I don't return an action from an effect, I get an error:

```
Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

I researched the issue and found that in an elm architecture there is something called a "noop" action that does nothing that you can call when you don't want to chain another action with your effect. Calling this noop action everywhere seems extremely repetitive to me. I am wondering if this would be a bad practice to follow. Is there a reason you cannot have an effect that does not return an action? Is the intention of effects to always have 1 action fire another action? I'm wondering if I am misunderstanding how to use effects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

By default, an ngrx/effect dispatches an action.

If you want an effect to be 'fire-and-forget', all you need to do is add `{dispatch: false}` as an argument to the `@Effects()` decorator.

From the [@ngrx/effects docs](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/api.md#effect):

> Observables decorated with the `@Effect()` decorator are expected to be a stream of actions to be dispatched. Pass `{ dispatch: false }` to the decorator to prevent actions from being dispatched.
>
> Usage:

```js
class MyEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) { }
    
  @Effect({ dispatch: false }) logActions$ = this.actions$
    .do(action => {
      console.log(action);
    });
}
```

Under the hood, this is achieved with the [`ignoreElements` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/ignoreelements.md). ([Here](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/src/effects.ts#L43) is the source-code of ngrx/effects if you are interested).
`ignoreElements` has a [built in noop function](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/headers/basicheader.js#L2) that gets [called](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/perf/operators/ignoreelements.js#L17) every time the effect runs.

In short, there is no need for an explicit noop-action in ngrx/effects. I wouldn't outright call it 'bad practice' to dispatch a noop-action, but it is certainly not necessary when using ngrx.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd suggest your changing the wording of *"This will complete the effects observable..."*. With observables, *complete* has a specific meaning and `{dispatch: false}` does not complete the observable. If it did, the effect would run only once.

Comment: You are right of course, the observable won't complete. I researched how ignoreElements works and it turns out it uses a noop-function itself. I changed my answer accordingly and made it a bit more concise, since I was reiterating what the docs say anyway :) Thanks!

Comment: Ah this makes sense. Great, strange how I missed this. Thanks!

Comment: When using the newer pipeable operators use tap() instead of do().

Comment: If you use `createEffect` factory, just add `{ dispatch: false }` as its second parameter.

Comment: What if you want to return an effect conditionally ?

Comment: @RoxTeddy It has been a while since I used Angular, so maybe there is a better way. But take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50975848/6745170). You could also go one step further and create two effects that filter the opposite condition of each other and then have one effect with `{ dispatch: false }` and the other returning an action.

Comment: An effect with conditional action is a very valid reason to require a no-op return value.