# ngrx Effects: Dispatch Empty Action

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

How do I get my ngrx/store effect to dispatch an empty action? I'm running Angular 6/rxjs 6:

```
  @Effect()
  testEffect$ = this.actions$.ofType(FIRST_ACTION).pipe(
    map((x) => {
       if (x === y) {
          return new SECOND_ACTION;
       } else {
          fire.some.effect;
          return EMPTY;
       }
    })
  );
```

At the moment, I'm getting two errors: `Effect "testEffect$" dispatched an invalid action: [object Object]` followed by `TypeError: Actions must have a type property`.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761826/how-to-dispatch-an-empty-action), but it doesn't seem to work with ng/rxjs 6. So far, I've tried the following (none work):

`EMPTY`, `Observable.empty()`, `Observable.of()` and `Observable.of([])`, `{ type: 'EMPTY_ACTION' }`

Any help would be appreciated! I know I can use `{ dispatch: false }`, but the actual effect has about five outcomes and only one of them doesn't use an action, so I'd rather have that last one return something as well.

Comment: What's `fire.some.effect`? Is it `this.store$.dispatch`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39762099/6680611

Comment: @martin - No, it's a reroute: `this.router.navigate(['url']);`
@cartant - Thanks for the link, but I already found your answer and I don't think it works with ng 6. At least none of the options you mentioned didn't do it for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
@Effect()
  testEffect$ = this.actions$.ofType(FIRST_ACTION).pipe(
    tap((x) => { // do some side effect here
        if (x !== y ) {
            fire.some.effect;
        }
    }),
    filter((x) => x === y), // proceed only if condition is true
    map((x) => {
       return new SECOND_ACTION; // then return the needed action
    })
  );
```

Comment: I would recommend to go even furhter and create two effects one with `{ dispatch: false }` that will have `x !== y` filter and the other with `x === y` filter.

Answer (score 3):

you could just use filter

```
@Effect()
testEffect$ = this.actions$.ofType(FIRST_ACTION).pipe(
  filter(x => x === y),
  map( x => new SECOND_ACTION)
)
```

and if you still need the other case you can write another effect with `dispatch: false`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (ng6) :

```
@Effect()
boardOpened$ = this.actions$
  .ofType<BoardActions.Open>(BoardActions.OPEN)
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(BoardSelectors.getState)),
    map(([action, state]: [Action, BoardReducer.State]) => {
      return !BoardReducer.isLoaded(state)
        ? new BoardActions.Load()
        : EMPTY;
    })
  );
```

or

```
@Effect()
boardOpened$ = this.actions$
  .ofType<BoardActions.Open>(BoardActions.OPEN)
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(BoardSelectors.getState)),
    switchMap(([action, state]: [Action, BoardReducer.State]) => {
      return !BoardReducer.isLoaded(state)
        ? of(new BoardActions.Load())
        : EMPTY;
    })
  );
```

Comment: Could you give some context as to what `EMPTY` is, or what package it comes from?

Comment: do not use `EMPTY` as it completes the stream and no further events are listened!

Comment: Mateo Tibaquira, sorry but I disagree. why ? Could you give some reference please? An HttpClient.get is also an observable that completes. See [https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#writing-effects](Official docs) that mentioned it to manage `catchError`. Thanks.